# Room persistence (java): My Update Query updates every value for that row. Can I make it more selective?

Tags: java, android, dao, android-room

**The background:** I have a survey app where I click buttons in a `recyclerView`, which updates the database using the update query defined in `Dao.java`. Then I have a results class where I get the database as a `List` using the query defined in the same place. I iterate over it, using a simple for loop (which is bad, but so am I), then post the string to an `editTextView`.

**The issue**:  Each update will update the fields of the subsequent columns. So everything works as expected if I fill in the questions 1 -> 15. But if `Person A` answers question 1 only, then starts the results activity and clicks the button which reveals every user's answer to question 2 (for example), then the answer for question 1 is revealed at Person A's row.
This will be masked (in most cases) if `Person A` continues and answers every question in sequence.
There will be still some glitches though, like question 4 will over-write question 5 in the data-base (but not the other way around). So if `Person A` changes his mind about question 4, we will have duplicate answers at 4 & 5.

**My thoughts:** I'm wondering if this is an SQL query error on my part or if maybe this is exactly why you should use a Repository (which I haven't). I'm basically terrible at this and will be grateful for any advice. Like all I want is to be better at this the next time.

Dao.java

```
@Entity(tableName = "surveyTable")
public class Model {


@PrimaryKey
public int person;
private int questionNumber1;



public int answer;


// allows Room to set every field of the table.

// these setter methods...
public Model(int person, int questionNumber1, int questionNumber2, int questionNumber3, int questionNumber4,
             int questionNumber5, int questionNumber6, int questionNumber7, int questionNumber8,
             int questionNumber9, int questionNumber10, int questionNumber11, int questionNumber12,
             int questionNumber13, int questionNumber14, int questionNumber15) 
{
    this.person = person;
    this.questionNumber1 = questionNumber1;


    this.answer = answer;
}

// and these getter methods ...
public int getPerson(){
    return person ;
}

public int getQuestionNumber1(){
    return questionNumber1;
}


public int getAnswer(){
    return answer;
}



// make it possible for Room to make objects for us but protects them

// from editing afterwards


}
```

`Results.java`. For each button, string/int [] and string there are 14 others which I deleted for readability. E.g. Private `int questionNumber1;` `Private int questionNumber2;` `Private int questionNumber3;` ... `Private int questionNumber15;`

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_results);

    resultsTextView = findViewById(R.id.resultsTextView);

    Q1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.resultsButton1);

    Q1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            resultsTextView.setText(answerString(1));
        }
    });


public String answerString(int i){
    int questionNumber = i - 1;
    String[] strings = answerArray();
    String questionNumberString =  strings[questionNumber];
    return questionNumberString;
}


public String[] answerArray(){
    List<Model> allItems2 = getDatabase(mContext).surveyDao().getAllItems();

    int q1;



    String str1 = "";



    String[] strings = new String[15];



    int[] a1 = new int[allItems2.size()];



    for (int i = 0; i < allItems2.size(); i++) {
        Model element = allItems2.get(i);

        q1 = element.getQuestionNumber1();


        a1[i] = q1;




    }


    for(int i=0;i<a2.length;i++) {

        str1 = str1 + Integer.toString(a1[i])+ "   ";


    }


    strings[0] = str1;

    return strings;

}
```

`ViewModel.java`. This has the `Async task` updating the database on button-push in the main activity. I was worried passing an extra variable, int q, to the method that wasn't looked for by the actual query but I needed some way to indicate what question we were answering.

```
    public void updateResult(int id, int answer, int q) {

    MyTaskParams params = new MyTaskParams(id, answer, q);
    addAsyncTask myTask = new addAsyncTask(appDatabase);
    new addAsyncTask(appDatabase).execute(params);
}




// Wrapping our primitives into a single, simple container so we can pass it to
// AsyncTask. Because the 1st param of AsyncTask<1st, 2nd, 3rd> goes into
// do inBackground [our workhouse background thread] which is what we want.
// But a comma for an extra variable [which is what we need] would feed that var
// into onProgressUpdate (Param 2). Not what we want.
private static class MyTaskParams {
    int id;
    int answer;
    int q;

    MyTaskParams(int id, int answer, int q) {
        this.id = id;
        this.answer = answer;
        this.q = q;
    }
}


// update
private static class addAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<MyTaskParams, Void, Void>{
    private AppDatabase db;


    addAsyncTask(AppDatabase appDatabase) {
        db = appDatabase;
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(MyTaskParams...params){
        int id = params[0].id;
        int answer = params[0].answer;
        int q = params[0].q;


        switch (q) {
            case (1):
                db.surveyDao().answer1(id, answer);
            case (2):
                db.surveyDao().answer2(id, answer);
            case (3):
                db.surveyDao().answer3(id, answer);
            case (4):
                db.surveyDao().answer4(id, answer);
            case (5):
                db.surveyDao().answer5(id, answer);
            case (6):
                db.surveyDao().answer6(id, answer);
            case (7):
                db.surveyDao().answer7(id, answer);
            case (8):
                db.surveyDao().answer8(id, answer);
            case (9):
                db.surveyDao().answer9(id, answer);
            case (10):
                db.surveyDao().answer10(id, answer);
            case (11):
                db.surveyDao().answer11(id, answer);
            case (12):
                db.surveyDao().answer12(id, answer);
            case (13):
                db.surveyDao().answer13(id, answer);
            case (14):
                db.surveyDao().answer14(id, answer);
            case (15):
                db.surveyDao().answer15(id, answer);

        }



        return null;
    }
}
```